# 大容量ストレージ装置のディスクの選び方について

Tags: ハードウェア

ディスクを何本も積める専用のストレージ装置についてです。
搭載できるディスクは300GB、600GB、900GBがあるものとします。
ディスク5本でRAID5を組む想定です。
別途、ホットスペア2本を搭載想定です。

例えば「20TB以上」を実現する場合、小さいディスクをたくさん積むのと、大きいディスクを少数積むのではどちらがベストプラクティスと考えられるでしょうか。

例：
300GB×5=1.5TB（実効容量1.2TB） × 17組 ≧ 20TB
900GB×5=4.5TB（実効容量3.6TB） × 6組 ≧ 20TB

小さいディスクをたくさん積んだ場合、万が一故障した時に被害が小さくて済みますが、数が多い分頻発する恐れがあると思えます。

大きいディスクを少数積んだ場合、数が少ないので故障発生の可能性は減りますが、故障した場合の被害が大きくなると思います。

ストレージ装置の設計は初めてのため、一般的な考え方があれば教えていただきたいです。
よろしくお願い致します。

※バックアップ運用の想定について
バックアップはストレージ装置の機能を使用し、ストレージ内の別領域に日次でコピーを行う想定です。
その後、LTOに書き込む運用とする想定です。

Comment: RAIDを構成するなら、RAIDのレベルを記入した方が想定が絞れて良いです。ディスクの本数とRAIDレベルの選択を総合して回答が欲しい場合は、そう書かれた方が良いです。

Comment: あとバックアップをどう運用するかの想定もあったほうが良いです。 RAID はバックアップの代わりにはなりません。複数台の装置が一度にぶっ壊れて RAID が復元できなくなる事態はまれによくあります。

Comment: 何を目的とするか、もあると良いように思います。コスト、耐障害性、可用性、メンテナンスの可否、などなど

Comment: コメントありがとうございます。
追記致しました

Comment: 搭載できるディスクの数には限りがあるはずで、将来の拡張性辺りも考慮する必要があるでしょう。 / 細かい話ですが、ディスク容量は`25GB, 500GB, 1TB`とかのキリがいい数字にしておいた方が分かりやすそうです。

Comment: RAID5が 17組とか6組と書かれてますが 20TBのRAID5ボリュームが必要というわけではないのでしょうか。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

一般論ですが、RAID5は、ディスクが多いほうが性能的に優れているので、どちらかというと 小容量のものをたくさんの方が良いと思います。

故障したときの被害は、システムが止まるリスクと、データが消えるリスクを分けて考えます。

システムが止まるリスクは RAID で対応します。
RAIDレベルによって、耐障害性、使える容量や性能に影響しますので 適切なものを選んでください。

データが消えるリスクは、RAID では対応できません。
バックアップとリストア、レプリケーションなどを検討します。

Answer (score 4):

こういう話はノウハウの類になるので、実経験者は NDA 縛りがあって答えられないとか、オイラみたいな部内サーバ管理者だと１０年以上前の「数百メガ」の経験しかないとかありそうですが・・・

予算と性能と信頼性は互いに反するところがあります。予算が無尽蔵にあるなら「一番いいのを頼む」で済むのですがなかなかそうもいかないでしょう。というわけで予算との兼ね合いは大事です。とりあえず以下では予算の話を除外します。

- RAID LEVEL

個人的には RAID5 は論外です。 RAID6 または RAID1 で運用したいところです。理由は単純、２台同時に壊れると RAID5 は破損するからです。１台故障して復元作業中にもう一台壊れるというのがまれによくあるセオリーで RAID5 ではどうにもなりませんが RAID6 ならまだなんとかなります。ホットスペアを用意できるならぜひ RAID6 にすることを検討してください。

RAID5 や RAID6 では速度低下しますが、それが許されないなら RAID1 のほうが良い結果を得られます。運用面では RAID1 ないしは RAID1+0 のほうが RAID6 より簡単です。特に、破損した RAID5/6 の修復を専門業者に頼むと費用が膨大になります。 RAID1 なら専門業者は要らないレベル。オイラが昔組んでた部内サーバでは結局 UWSCSI ディスク４台で RAID1+0 にしてしまいました。

- RAID 組数

RAID5 は最低３台で組めて、何台で組んでも１台故障まで運用可能
RAID6 は最低４台で組めて、何台で組んでも２台故障まで運用可能
なので RAID6 を４台で組むのが障害発生確率が最低となることになります。組み台数を増やすと容量効率は上がりますが障害発生の可能性は上がります。その辺は設計っつか運用っつか次第。

- インターフェイス

高速高価高信頼性の SAS と、低価格 SATA と言われています。秋葉原にいくと SATA ディスクが「常時通電サーバ用」と「夜は電源を切るクライアント用」でシリーズが別になっていますが、そもそも SATA の高信頼性装置より SAS の通常装置のほうが信頼性が高いとされています。あとは負荷と信頼性と価格でどちらを選ぶか決めてください。オイラが選ぶなら
- 部内サーバ（使用者２０名共用リポジトリ利用で停止しても１日くらいならなんとかできる）なら SATA
- 社内サーバ（使用者１０００名以上、ミッションクリティカルでこれが止まると全社の仕事が停止する）なら SAS

テラスケールの 24/365 常時運用なら、ディスク装置自体の信頼性を含めて SAS

質問分中の 600G や 900G といった表記は SAS 装置で標準的な容量なので、質問者様も SAS 装置を予定しているのでしょう。オイラも SAS 装置に強く同意します。

でも今なら PCI-x4 以上接続の SSD でソフトウエア RAID1+0 のほうがユーザーに受け入れられるかも。

- ディスク装置の手配

同一メーカーの同一ロット装置を使って RAID を組むと同時に壊れます。異メーカー異シリーズ異ロットのものを手配したいです。

- １装置あたりの容量

将来、小容量のものは入手困難になりそうなので大容量のものを使いたいです。

Answer (score 2):

> ディスク5本でRAID5を組む想定です。

ストレージであればRAID5は普通使いません。6(または同等以上のメーカー独自方式)一択です。

> 別途、ホットスペア2本を搭載想定です。

ホットスペアの本数は固定で考えてはいけません。ディスク本数が多いならホットスペアにするディスクも増やすべきですし、筐体内でしか構成できないなど制限があればそれにも従う必要があります。

> 小さいディスクをたくさん積んだ場合、万が一故障した時に被害が小さくて済みますが、数が多い分頻発する恐れがあると思えます。
>   大きいディスクを少数積んだ場合、数が少ないので故障発生の可能性は減りますが、故障した場合の被害が大きくなると思います。

ディスク本数が多ければ故障も増えるので、その点では本数が少ないほうがよいのは間違いないです。しかし、故障で被害が生じた場合、その被害は、どちらも質問の例では20TBです。故障した場合の被害を下げるなら、20TBのボリュームを作るのではなく、10TB×2にするとかそういう検討が必要です。

というところで前提がいろいろおかしいです。

---

ワークロードが書かれてないのですが、まずワークロード次第でディスクの種類を選択します。ランダムアクセスが多いならSAS、アーカイブ的な使い方ならSATA、とかです。コストが高いからランダムアクセスが多いけどSATAにする、というようなことは普通ありません。DASにすることを検討します。逆に、アーカイブなのにSASにする、ということも通常ありません。真っ先にコスト削減のターゲットになります。

RAID構成は前述の通り6(または同等以上のメーカー独自方式)一択です。ほかのRAIDを検討する必要があるなら、これもDASへの切り替えの方をまず検討した方がよいです。

RAID1セットのディスク本数の推奨の構成(例えば8D+2P)みたいなのはメーカーが持っているので、それに従えばあとはほぼ機械的に構成は決まります。推奨は推奨なので、違う構成にすることもありますが、裏付けが必要です。製品の仕様もあり、例えば2D+2Pみたいな構成はストレージではサポートされてないと思います。

基本的には同じディスクの種類でコストが高いものを選択する理由はありません。なので、

> 300GB×5=1.5TB（実効容量1.2TB） × 17組 ≧ 20TB
>   900GB×5=4.5TB（実効容量3.6TB） × 6組 ≧ 20TB

のどっちがいいか、という疑問には普通ならないわけです。

ディスクの種類云々はディスクオンリーだったころの話で、最近はSSD+そこそこの性能のディスクという構成で大容量とか低コストを実現することもあるので、一概には言えなくなってきています。

いずれにせよ、製品ごとの推奨構成はありますので、結局はメーカーに相談するのが一番早道で確実です。

---

どちらかというとストレージ設計でめんどくさいのは、用途と容量、将来の拡張の必要性みたいなところを整理するところです。ここを間違えると、必要な性能が出ない、容量が足りないが仕様いっぱいいっぱいで拡張がままならない、とかそういうことになります。

たとえば、バックアップのことが書かれていますが、容量だけ考えてSATAのボリューム使ってD2D2Tしようとしたらバックアップ周期に全然間に合わない、とかそういう事例もあります。